# How to convert a python long (16byte uuid) to a numpy unsigned int64 array?

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion, long-integer, uuid

I am trying to find the best way to store a 16byte (128bit) long int (the int representation of a uuid.UUID object) in python by means of converting it first to a `numpy.ndarray(dtype=np.uint64, shape=(2, ))` object.

I understand the the internal memory representation of python long is not trivial, so I assume that there is are no 16bytes in memory I could just use to construct the `numpy.array`.

My current solution (python 2.7) is to use manual shifting on long ints which works, but is by no means elegant and fast.

```python
import numpy as np

py_long = 0x1234567890abcdf8888888877777777L

# from (16byte) long to int64-array
np_arr = np.array([py_long >> 64, py_long & 0xffffffffffffffff], dtype=np.uint64)

# from int64 array to (16byte) long
py_long = (long(np_arr[0]) << 64) + long(np_arr[1])
```

My specific question would be if there are simpler and faster ways to cast these in both ways.

Comment: If you still have the `uuid.UUID` instance around: it has a `bytes` and a `bytes_le` attribute with the 16 bytes in big and little endian order.

Comment: Why is the obvious way (shifting and masking) not elegant? How an `int` is represented internally is an implementation detail, so there isn't really another choice when all you have is an `int` (in Python 2.7).